# how to remove a small line between TabView to ScrollListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have the following xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.me"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/blue_bg">

    <!--  Title bar -->
    <com.me.view.title.TitleBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rtalterts_list_title_bar" />

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <com.me.view.tabs.TabBar
        android:id="@+id/ReportTabBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rtalterts_list_title_bar"
        app:type="tabs3" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rtalterts_list_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ReportTabBar"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/transparent_full"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the xml for each row in the listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.me"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rtalerts_list_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/alt_routes_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Title container -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rtalerts_list_item_title_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.77">

       ...
    </LinearLayout> <!-- Details container -->


    <!-- Distance container -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rtalerts_list_item_distance_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.23">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rtalerts_list_item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/alert_icon_traffic_info" 
            android:layout_weight="0.40"/>
        <!-- Distance text container -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="5.15" >
```

...

nowadays I have a small blue line (@color/blue_bg)

between the tabs and the list.

how can I remove it?

I made sure padding is 0:

```
private void init( Context context, int type )
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    inflater.inflate( R.layout.tabs, this );

    setPadding( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the root layout for your tabs.xml?

Comment: BTW, you should change `android:layout_below="@+id/ReportTabBar"` to `android:layout_below="@id/ReportTabBar"`. Use `@+id` only once for each variable.

Comment: @Vaiden my bad styling

Comment: @Szymon thanks. any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the hierarchy viewer to determine precisely which control is causing the additional padding, and exposing the blue background between the TabBar and the ListView.

Most likely is that the background of the TabBar includes some padding in its nine patch to allow for the subtle shadow. You could perhaps override the background of the TabBar by providing `android:background="@null"`, although I can't say for certain that this will work without seeing the implementation of that custom component.

Comment: It's padding. when I have changed to @null, the lines changed black. But hard for me to see which component causes this

Comment: You could instead use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` if the black background is making it difficult to see the problem. The View Hierarchy tool may make it easier for you to see the exact dimensions of each component.